# SAXParseException when invoking web service from web application deployed on web sphere

Tags: web-services, websphere, webservice-client

I am invoking web service from web application that is deployed on web sphere 8 (both service and Client),    when i am trying to invoke web service from web sphere client it is throwing exception shown below,   I am able test the service from SOAP UI. there is no problem with WSDL as such. Not able to understand what could go wrong

```
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2255)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2330)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2296)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper$13.run(WSDL4JWrapper.java:732)
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:132)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.loadDefinition(WSDL4JWrapper.java:729) 195 more
Caused by:     
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2245)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing issue, WSDL was not accessible because of some change to the web service, after providing right path to the WSDL issue got resolved, i.e  service_name?wsdl was not accessible i had to give the complete URL to the  WSDL file

Thanks,